# Why is badge 'Constable' awarded 0 times?

Tags: support, badges

When going through the badge section, I saw that the badge *Constable* was awarded 0 times:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/3108/constable

Why hasn't it been awarded to a single person yet?

Comment: I'm guessing because no-one meets that criteria?

Comment: Pro-tem moderator for one year.. It's unbelievable no one still met the criteria

Comment: https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/07/27/moderator-pro-tempore/ They are actually "pro tem" when they are appointed for beta sites from area 51. I dont think it refers to regular mods.

Comment: So I guess the badge itself was created for participation in newer sites. May not be possible to get in Stackoverflow.

Comment: Even Jon Skeet himself doesn't have a Constable badge!!

Answer (score 29):

This badge cannot be awarded on Stack Overflow since it only has elected moderators.

Constable can only be achieved on Stack Exchange sites in public beta.

Comment: Why is it on StackOverflow if it cant be awarded? is it just for display? xD

Comment: @Anonymouse We try to keep the badge lists consistent across sites as much as possible.