# Appointed moderator doesn't have Constable badge?

Tags: bug, badges, moderators

Related: [Why is badge 'Constable' awarded 0 times?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344728/5958455)

On the [moderators page](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators), one of our moderators is shown as "appointed", as seen below:

[image]

Why doesn't Myers have a *Constable* badge?

Comment: Your "Related" question that you cited explains exactly why.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Constable isn't awarded for being appointed. It is awarded for serving as a pro-tem moderator during the beta period. He did not do that. It's just that in the early days before moderators were elected, they were appointed by the staff.