# What is a pro-tem moderator on Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, badges, description

The description of the Constable badge on https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges reads:

> Served as a pro-tem moderator for at least 1 year or through site graduation

Is `pro-tem` a typo? And if it is not a typo, what does `pro-tem` mean?

*Edit*:

As specified in the comments, it is not a typo.
How does it happen, on Stack Exchange sites, that someone can serve as a `pro-tem` moderator? In which situations would this occur?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro_tempore (mods who are appointed, not elected)

Comment: Thank you! When does this situation happen in SE sites?

Comment: [Why is badge 'Constable' awarded 0 times?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344728/1364007)

Comment: Thanks @WaiHaLee, the blogpost answers my question.

Comment: See also https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/66134/is-there-a-word-for-temporary-but-may-become-permanent/66153#66153

Comment: It appears to be a typo of _pro tem_. "Pro-tem" (with a hyphen) would mean "in favour of tem".

Answer (score 8):

I would strongly suggest updating the wording of the "Constable" badge to have the full "pro tempore" phrase instead of the unnecessary and confusing "pro-tem" contraction.

Answer (score 6):

As pointed out in the comments, pro-tem means `pro tempore`, and in the context of Stack Exchange, this corresponds to appointed moderators which are appointed as moderators on public Beta shortly after the start of the public Beta before the first elections are held according to this blog-post:
https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/07/27/moderator-pro-tempore/